# TypeScript: interface how to extends a type that retrieved from other interface with a property

Tags: typescript

```
interface Element {
    name: string
    position: {
        x: number
        y: number
    }
}

type Pos = Element['position']

interface Pos1 extends Position { } // works here
interface Pos2 extends Element['position'] { } // not work!!
```

I want to know why the second line is wrong?
I don't want to use the first line, It's trouble. But the second line is not works. I'm said.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a suggestion on github to this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31843

Generelly speaking - `Element['position']` (when extending the `class` or `interface`) is evaluated to expression, not a type.

You can workaround it by:

1. as you did by declaring the type first `type Pos = Element['position']`.
2. make it more generic, to reuse this along your project:

   ```
   type Take<T> = T
   interface Bar extends Take<Element['position']> {

   }
   ```
3. Hackky workaround:

   ```
   interface Bar extends Omit<Element['position'], ''> {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a type/interface to your `position` key

```
interface Pos {
        x: number
        y: number
    }

interface Element {
    name: string
    position: Pos
}



interface Pos1 extends Pos { 
 z:number;
} 

const test: Pos1 = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
}
```